# How to run Apache as another user? (as 'www', or 'apache') on my

Tags: apache-2.2, security, httpd.conf, user-accounts

I just recently deployed a LAMP stack that came as a package for Linode (a VPS host), I can successfully run Apache 2 but the process and all my files within are owned by `root`. On my shared web host I could run as nobody or similar to help restrict access, how can I do this myself on my VPS?

I think the steps would be:
 - Create user `apache2`
 - Write in httpd.conf to use `apache2`?
 - recursively chown all my files to `apache2`.

I simply can not find a solution except to use another package and have it installed like that, I would really enjoy some guidence on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`User`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user) directive sets the user httpd runs as, if for some reason the distro doesn't set it in its package.

Comment: Awesome, it is ran under nobody now. Should I chown everything in `/srv/www/foo.com/public_html` to nobody now?

Comment: If that makes sense in your situation, sure. Don't forget to set `Group` as well.